# Error when converting ui. file to py. file

Tags: python, django, qt

I'm using Windows 8 64 bit and Python 2.7. I have downloaded and installed [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) and desigined a GUI in QT designer. I know that I'm supposed to convert ui to py using pyuic4, but when I write this command in cmd (in the ui's path):

```
pyuic4 -x GUI.ui -o GUI.py
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py", line 31, in <module>
from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Edit: the new error is this now,

```
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

I'm sure I installed PyQt4, and it is in the side-packages folder. Any idea how to make python recognize it?

Comment: Have you added the Qt path to the PATH environment variable? Also, are you sure that you are not mixing 32 and 64 bits? You need to have 32 bit or 64 bit for python and Qt, but not a mixture.

Comment: Please do not change the question from one error to another. Just leave it with the original error, and at worst add the new, too, but do not delete the old. It triggers any answer solving that for you looking bad and incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

It seems that you are mixing 32 and 64 bit python and python modules. The easiest solution is to use 32 bit for each of them, alongside the Qt dlls.

The more difficult solution than the previous would be to get everything in 64, but modules are often not available so, so you might need to hand-craft it yourself.

For a quick solution, I would suggest the former, i.e. using 32 bits as of now.

Comment: Thanks, I've done what you said, but there's another problem. Please look at the edit I've just made to the question.

Comment: @gilgemer: is it in the PYTHONPATH? Check the content of that variable. Try to add `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` to it if it is missing.

Comment: I've addded it to the pythonpath but it's still the same importError

Comment: @gilgemer: show your whole code... Also, how did you install Qt 4 and pyqt4? Have you hand-craftem them or just used the installer proper?